# Amazon Athena select entire JSON row

Tags: hive, presto, amazon-athena

In Amazon Athena,

I have some data file in form of one JSON on one row

```
{ a: 1, b: 2 }
{ a: 2, b: 4 }
{ a: 3, b: 6 }
```

is it possible to output entire row of data while the table is created with only field `a`?

```
SELECT ??? FROM table1 WHERE a > 1;
```

Output

```
{ a: 2, b: 4 }
{ a: 3, b: 6 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes if your column is a `JSON` then you can extract it in `Athena` as so:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE cast(json_extract_scalar(column_name,
         '$.a') as integer) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is function  **concat( sting,string,...)** in hive which can be used but I doubt Athena supports UDFs  .

Sample code

```
SELECT concat('{ a: ' , cast(a as string),', b:' ,cast(a as string), ' }' )FROM table1 WHERE a > 1;
```

**Update after comment**

In case you have to create table form limited column create view on top of base table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, my json data row has a hundred of attributes. There are too many fields and I pick some of them to create the table. I use those field for filtering. However, in some use case. I would get the entire row of data.

Comment: in that case create view on top of base table.